# Windows CE 7 SPI Driver Not Loaded at Startup

Tags: windows-ce, device-driver, spi

I am a newbie.

I want to develop device drivers on Windows CE 7.

I use Adeneo BSP on TI AM33xx Development Board

I want to drive a SPI Flash so I should use SPI driver.

I have written my driver and when I debug it, all functions calling correctly. But when I call the

```
CreateFile( _T("SPI1:"),
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

deviceHandle always return invalid value. So when I debug the low level SPI driver, I seen , SPI_Init() stream function never called.

There is this tines in my platform.reg file

```
;===============================================================================
; MCSPI driver
#include "$(_PLATFORMROOT)\AM33x_BSP\SRC\DRIVERS\MCSPI\mcspi.reg"
```

And

My mcspi.reg file is

```
;-- SPI Driver -----------------------------------------------------------------
IF BSP_AM33X_MCSPI1
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\BuiltIn\SPI1]
    "Prefix"="SPI"
    "Dll"="am33x_mcspi.dll"
    "Index"=dword:1
    "Port"=dword:1
    "Order"=dword:8
    "MemBase"=multi_sz:"48030000"
    "MemLen"=multi_sz:"00000100"
    "Timeout"=dword:300
    "PowerFlags"=dword:00000103              ; send pre/post device state changes
    ; PMCLASS_PMEXT_GUID
    "IClass"=multi_sz:"{0AE2066F-89A2-4D70-8FC2-29AEFA68413C}"
ENDIF
```

**[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\BuiltIn\SPI1]** this lines say to us, "SPI1 driver will be loaded at startup", isnt it ??? But spi driver SPI_Init function never loaded at starttup. I havent seen any extra setting in Microsoft White Paper.

And additional,

I have tried

```
ActivateDeviceEx(TEXT("Drivers\\BuiltIn\\SPI1"), NULL, 0, NULL);
```

and

```
LoadLibrary(TEXT("am33x_mcspi.dll"));
```

functions but result is same.

Is there any extra setting for Driver Loading?

Thanks

Murat.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your driver is compiled to your flat release directory. Then, add your driver to your platform.bib file. something like this:

```
am33x_mcspi.dll $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\am33x_mcspi.dll NK SH
```